# CodeLens for JUnit test funtions desn't appear in VSCode

Tags: java, junit, visual-studio-code

I have all prerequisites (JDK, Language Support for Java by Red Hat, and Debugger for Java) of Java extension on VSCode but CodeLens doesn't appear for JUnit test functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified  `.classpath` file of my project from this:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" />
```

to this:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="build/classes/test">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="test" value="true" />
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

It fixed the problem. For more information see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/470#issuecomment-444681714).